# How to automatically execute a command every time a certain application is launched?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am reading [this manual](http://wiki.opencog.org/w/Getting_Started_with_Atoms_and_the_Scheme_Shell) about the `guile` program - every time this program is started the user is advised to enter some 5-10 lines of special commands. They say that it is possible to create a file and write those commands in this file and then commands from this file are run as the first commands when the certain command (guile in this case) is started.

They provide command `$ vim ~/.guile` for creating such file but I don't understand it. So there are subquestions:

- In which directory should I create file for the first commands for guile?
- How can I indicate that this file should be used upon start of guile? Does Ubuntu have some global registry where such information (about triggers for the programs) are stored?

Comment: Thanks! I understand that vim editor, but I can not understand where this new file is stored and how can Ubuntu know that this file should be executed upon startup of guile. I want control over this process - e.g. to open file from the explorer and edit, add additional content.

Answer (score 4):

The command `vim ~/.guile` will create a file `.guile` in the directory `~/`, which is shorthand for your user's home directory. The leading `.` makes it hidden from file managers by default, to minimize visual clutter so to open and edit it from the file manager you will need to check the 'Show hidden files' option (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>).

You do not need to use the `vim` editor: `nano ~/.guile` or `gedit ~/.guile` will work just as well.

You do not need to do anything to indicate that `guile` should use the file on startup - there is no global registry, each program knows about and checks for its own configuration files. For example, `vim` itself searches for a `~/.vimrc` file and so on.